# Appium iOS is finding thousands of elements before it clicks freezing the test

Tags: ruby, appium, appium-ios

I have a page in my application that has a tutorial overlay. I want appium to just tap the screen to get rid of the overlay and then continue doing tests. For some reason the tap command I send never happens and the test times out. I'm not explicitly waiting more than 2 seconds to initiate the tap and from what I can tell the tap is sent but just doesn't happen.

Thank you for any help you can give regarding this issue. I'm already attempting to work with my devs on this but so far we've not been able to come up with a solution.

Appium Logs (This is the moment the appium project runs in to the screen with the overlay and multiple users):

```
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"status":0,"id":"446B2970-66EA-4795-846E-250B55EFABC0","value":"","sessionId":"C0E25E26-64C1-4E83-BEB5-5CA7CE029299"}
[JSONWP Proxy] Replacing sessionId C0E25E26-64C1-4E83-BEB5-5CA7CE029299 with 83022946-db67-4a8c-bdbe-4b1f203a2763
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/83022946-db67-4a8c-bdbe-4b1f203a2763/element/446B2970-66EA-4795-846E-250B55EFABC0/click 200 548 ms - 118 
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/83022946-db67-4a8c-bdbe-4b1f203a2763/touch/perform {"actions":[{"action":"tap","options":{"x":0.5,"y":0.5,"count":1}},{"action":"release"}]}
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.performTouch() with args: [[{"action":"tap","options":{"x":0.5,"y":0.5,"count":1}},{"action":"release"}],"83022946-db67-4a8c-bdbe-4b1f203a2763"]
[debug] [XCUITest] Executing command 'performTouch'
[debug] [XCUITest] Received the following touch action: tap(options={"x":0.5,"y":0.5,"count":1})-release
[debug] [XCUITest] Found matching gesture: tap
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /wda/tap/0] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/C0E25E26-64C1-4E83-BEB5-5CA7CE029299/wda/tap/0] with body: {"x":0.5,"y":0.5}
[BaseDriver] Shutting down because we waited 60 seconds for a command
[Appium] Closing session, cause was 'New Command Timeout of 60 seconds expired. Try customizing the timeout using the 'newCommandTimeout' desired capability'
[Appium] Removing session 7d24454e-3b9f-434c-a43a-d1f301b1802f from our master session list
[XCUITest] Shutting down sub-processes
[debug] [XCUITest] Found WDA derived data folder: '/Users/jessefish/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy'
[XCUITest] Setting '755' permissions to '/Users/jessefish/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Logs/Test/Attachments' folder
[debug] [XCUITest] Found WDA derived data folder: '/Users/jessefish/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs'
[XCUITest] Setting '755' permissions to '/Users/jessefish/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Logs/Test/Attachments' folder
[debug] [XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.
[debug] [iOSLog] Stopping iOS log capture
```

Comment: Can you add some logs? With this information, its difficult to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its possible. iOS provides the full list of items on the screen. So if you have a scrollable view, and say it has 1000 items, then Appium will get all the items even though only few will be visible on the screen at a time.

One thing that can be done is to avoid using xpath as much as possible. And then to adsk dev to add automation ids to all the controls. This way, even if you need to use xpath, the list can be narrowed down as you get a very targetted list based on automation ids.

Another thing that can be done is (only if you want to verify if element exists) get the page source once. then just search for the value in the page source text. This will speed up execution a lot, but only where you want to check if element exists.